# Implementing countdown js count down inside php code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, countdowntimer, throttling

I completed my php code for throttling login, however now I want to use simple js or jquery code to get the throttling count down time from the php and make a live countdown.

Should I put the js script in the php file? or the html file? If so, how should I edit my code to work?

So far I have put the span id timer into the php which now shows the timer but again I dont get the php live timer

My php code:

```
<?php
include('database.php');
function get_multiple_rows($getfailed) {
    $rows = array();
    while($row = $getfailed->fetch_assoc()) {
        $rows[] = $row;
    }
    return $rows;
}
$throttle = array(1 => 1, 5 => 2, 10 => 30);
$getfailedq = "SELECT MAX(attempted) AS attempted FROM failed_logins";    
if ($getfailed = $mySQL->query($getfailedq)) {
    $rows = get_multiple_rows($getfailed);
    $getfailed->free();
    $latest_attempt = (int) date('U', strtotime($rows[0]['attempted'])); 
    $getfailedq = "SELECT COUNT(1) AS failed FROM failed_logins WHERE attempted > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 minute)";   
    if ($getfailed = $mySQL->query($getfailedq)) {
        $rows = get_multiple_rows($getfailed);
        $getfailed->free();
        $failed_attempts = (int) $rows[0]['failed'];
        krsort($throttle);
        foreach ($throttle as $attempts => $delay) {
            if ($failed_attempts > $attempts) {
                $remaining_delay = (time() - $latest_attempt) - $delay;
                if ($remaining_delay < 0) {echo '<span id="timer">' . abs($remaining_delay) . '</span>';}                
                break;
            }
        }        
    }
}
?>
```

My js:

```
<script>
var count=30;
var counter=setInterval(timer, 1000); //1000 will  run it every 1 second
function timer(){
    count=count-1;
    if (count <= 0){
        clearInterval(counter);
        return;
    }
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML=count + " secs"; // watch for spelling
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initialize your JS variable by an PHP variable liek this:

```
var counter = <?php echo $counter; ?>;
```

And create your counter in JS.

**EDIT #1:**
After initializing the variable you need to count it down.

```
var counter = <?php echo $counter; ?>;  
setInterval(function () {
    console.log(counter);
    counter--;
}, 1000 /*ms*/ );
```